# typeof of boolean expression with comparison operator

Tags: javascript, operator-precedence, typeof

```
if (typeof foo !== 'undefined') {
    // Now we know that foo is defined, we are good to go.
}
```

The `typeof` evaluates to `true` or `false` based on whether the variable `foo` is defined or not.

But, say if `foo !== 'undefined'` evaluates to `true`, then `typeof` of `true` should evaluate to `'boolean'`.
Why does it evaluate to `true` or `false`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because precedence rules for the `typeof` and inquality operators define that that expression is parsed as

```
(typeof foo) !== 'undefined'
```

For more information, see the [MDN page on operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence). `typeof` is precedence 16; inquality is precedence 10. The higher precedence of `typeof` means that it "binds" more tightly to its operand.

By the way, why do you have undefined variables in your code?

Comment: For reference, `typeof (typeof foo !== 'undefined')` would do what OP thinks.